Docker Server Crashes on Client Request
This is my first time trying to implement docker for deployment. I have all my program files in a folder called 'app' and I have the following Dockerfile code:
FROM python:3.12

# Path: /app

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r /code/requirements.txt

COPY ./app /code/app

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.server:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "5000"]

I am using a very basic server with fastAPI that has two branches.
server.py:
from fastapi import FastAPI
import joblib
import numpy as np
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

model = joblib.load('app/model.joblib')

class_names = np.array(['setosa','versicolor','virginica'])

app = FastAPI()

# Basic response for API root
@app.get('/')
def read_root():
    return {'message': 'Iris model API'}

# Predict label based on sent post request data
@app.post('/predict')
def predict(data: dict):
    features = np.array(data['features'].reshape(1,-1))
    prediction = model.predict(features)
    class_name = class_names[prediction][0] # Get the string label for model prediction
    return {'prediction': class_name}

/predict request uses a dummy scikit-learn model that was saved in a model.joblib file  that is also in the same directory (inside the app folder). For reference, here's a screenshot of the project environment:

For clarification, model.py is not a dependency affecting the server. It was only meant to train and build a very basic dummy ai model using scikit-learn, which is already saved in model.joblib.
I first run docker build -t ai-template . to build the image, and then run docker run --name container-name -p 5000:5000 ai-template to run the server, which is successful and I get the following output:
INFO:     Started server process [1]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

However, when I try to use the local host link to see what the server returns, it keeps crashing and I am unable to use the server. Do you know what the issue may be? Any help is appreciated.

For more detail: my requirements.txt file includes scikit-learn, fastapi, numpy, uvicorn, and logging as dependencies. Thanks

What does "keep crashing" entail? Do you get an error in the log? Does the docker daemon report anything for the container? Are you running the container in the same environment you used outside of Docker? (i.e. does it have enough memory, any required hardware, etc.)?
